# Make value ranges to guess

Tags: probability, excel

Hi I have excel sheet with following like data of shoppers and money they used:

```
CUSTOMER      MONEY USED
teen          5
pensioner     15
teen          9
adult         35
teen          2
pensioner     5
adult         17
...
```

Now **I need to find value ranges to make guess** is shopper teen, adult or pensioner based on money they used.

For example values could be something like:

```
0–8.25      = teen
8.26–14.31  = pensioner
14.31–      = adult
```

And if I have someone would use 13$ he or she would be pensioner with the highest probability.

What would be best way to calculate this kind of values?

Any kind of help would be much appreciated!

Comment: As I understood, the "CUSTOMER" column contains your class labels. So, the prediction would be based on the other features. If this is true, then I don't understand why you would need to have a range for categorical values? Normally, there are numerical values, and to make it work as labels, we may need to discretized them and treat them as categorical values. But not the other way around! In you case, for instance, if you had the customers' age, you would want to categorize them into n age-range.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a logistic regression with "type" as the dependent variable and "money spent" as the IV. From that, you can get the probability of each type at each level of money.

I don't know if this is possible in Excel but a) I wouldn't use Excel for statistics and b) Coding questions are off topic here.